# Matrix Transformation in GLSL not working

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, graphics, 3d

So what I'm trying to do is make a transformation matrix for 2D GUI objects. When I multiply my three transformation matrices together, Rotation and Scale actually effect the rotation and scale of the object, but not Position. I checked in GDebugger, and the matrix is being properly calculated, but for some reason, the position doesn't seem to effect the vertex in any way.

Here's the relevant c++ code:

```
void GUIRenderer::setPosition(float x, float y)
{
    Position = glm::vec2(x, y);
    Pos_Mat = glm::mat3(
        1, 0, x,
        0, 1, y,
        0, 0, 1
        );
    Transformation = Sca_Mat*Rot_Mat*Pos_Mat;
}
void GUIRenderer::setRotation(float _Rot)
{
    Rotation = _Rot;
    Rot_Mat = glm::mat3(
        cos(Rotation), sin(Rotation), 0,
        -sin(Rotation), cos(Rotation), 0,
        0, 0, 1
        );
    Transformation = Sca_Mat*Rot_Mat*Pos_Mat;
}
void GUIRenderer::setScale(float x, float y)
{
    Scale = glm::vec2(x, y);
    Sca_Mat = glm::mat3(
        x, 0, 0,
        0, y, 0,
        0, 0, 1
        );
    Transformation = Sca_Mat*Rot_Mat*Pos_Mat;
}

void GUIRenderer::Update()
{
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glUseProgram(GUI_material->Program);
    glUniform3f(GUI_material->Color_Uniform, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    pos++;
    setPosition(pos, 0.0f);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(GUI_material->Trans_Uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, &Transformation[0][0]);
    GUI_material->RefreshTexture();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->Vertices.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3), &mesh->Vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GUI_material->Position_Attribute);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GUI_material->Position_Attribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->UVs.size()*sizeof(glm::vec2), &mesh->UVs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GUI_material->TexCoord_Attribute);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GUI_material->TexCoord_Attribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->Triangles.size()*sizeof(int), &mesh->Triangles[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

And here is the relevant GLSL code:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

uniform mat3 Trans;

out vec2 Texcoord;

void main() {
   Texcoord = texcoord;
   vec3 _pos = Trans*vec3(position.xy, 1.0);
   gl_Position = vec4(_pos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Here's the gDebugger output for what's being sent to the Shader
GDebugger Output for what's being sent to the shader

```
Trans GL_FLOAT _MAT3
{0.00014815529, 0.49999997, 562}
{-0.49999997, 0.00014815529, 0}
{0, 0, 1}
```

Did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the "matrix * vector" multiplication order in your shader. You must build your matrices following this convention. OpenGL will use *column major* order for matrices, so your `setPosition` function creates a matrix where it put  the `x` and `y` translation parts into the last *row* instead of the last column. Now this has no effect at all, because in your shader, you completely ignore the `_pos.z` value which would have been screwed up by this.

Interestingly, you have taken the transposition into account for building your rotation matrix (the minus sign is at the first row, second column), so only your translation matrix is transposed, the rest will work as-is.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what I'm supposed to correct based on that.
[EDIT:Stupid Enter Button]
What you're saying is that it's essentially putting x and y into the bottom row of the matrix, rather than on the leftmost column?

Comment: yes. your translation matrix is transposed to what it should look like.

Comment: Alright. That did it. I'm gonna look into my rotation function, because I think it's working backwards from where it's supposed to...

Comment: @AndrewQ: As I already pointed out, your rotation matrix is actually correct. However, for rotations, the transposition is the inverse, so if you transpose it, the rotation direction will flip. Note that in the "correct" way, the mathematically positive rotation is counter-clockwise. Maybe you expect it the other way around?

Comment: @Andrew Q: Everything should be clear if you think of matrix multiplication as working in a "postfix" manner. You have a position row vector (a,b,1) and you multiply your transformation on the right, postfix style.

Comment: @derhass technically, it was wrong, because I wanted it to rotate using a right hand coordinate system. Positive Rotation was supposed to be CCW not CW.

Comment: @derhass nevermind. Just verified it. That means my source transposed them, apparently.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle I think that's an answer to a different problem. I understand how matrices are multiplied, I just wasn't getting correct behavior from my matrices because they were being transposed.